# How to get the next node's child value inside a for-loop in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to access a value from the next node inside a for loop in XSLT.

The XML source is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree>
<parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <child>
        <effective_date>01-09-2019</effective_date>
        <hours>10</hours>
        <dept>1</dept>
    </child>
    <child>
        <effective_date>01-10-2019</effective_date>
        <hours>20</hours>
        <dept>1</dept>
    </child>
    <child>
        <effective_date>01-10-2019</effective_date>
        <class>A</class>
    </child>
</parent>
    <parent>
        <id>2</id>
        <child>
            ...
        </child>
        <child>
            ..
        </child>
    </parent>
</tree>
```

The desired output is that I want the next child node's Effective_date value in first validUntil tag in result like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <departments>
        <department>
            <code>1</code>
            <weeklyHours>10</weeklyHours>
            <validFrom>2019-09-09</validFrom>
            <validUntil>2019-10-01</validUntil
        </department>
        <department>
            <code>1</code>
            <weeklyHours>20</weeklyHours>
            <validFrom>2019-10-01</validFrom>
            <validUntil/>
        </department>
    </departments>
</employees>
```

In my original xslt, I am inside a for loop, which I am entering conditionally based on whether a child element has change in hours or not. So this has to be accessed inside a for loop.

Comment: I don't see following-sibiling of  'weci:Effective_Change' as `weci:Effective_Moment`?

Comment: @AmrendraKumar : So basically, I want to access the next Effective_Change's , weci:Effective_Moment. I am not sure, how this can be achieved while I am still in the first iteration of for-each loop.

Comment: You would get better answer with a minimum sample and not your actual data. Also, those nested `xsl:choose` are not the typical XSLT flow.

Comment: I have now modified it to a simpler version to explain what I need to achieve in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `xsl:for-each` is iterating over sibling elements, then you can get the next element using `following-sibling::*`

If you are iterating over an arbitrary sequence $SEQ, then you can get the next element using:

- XSLT 2.0: `subsequence($SEQ, position()+1, 1)`
- XSLT 1.0: `<xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/><xsl:.... select="$SEQ[$p+1]"/>`

Don't make the mistake of using `$SEQ[position()+1]` - the value of `position()` changes within a predicate.

Comment: Thank you. I used following-sibling : : *[1]/ in a second xslt which I used over the output xml from my first xslt and it solved my problem.